# One UIView in multiple TableViewCells

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiview

I have a `UITableViewCell` which contains an `UIView`.

This `UIView` is larger than the `UITableViewCell` and should also be visible in the `cell` above.

```
clipsToBounds=NO
```

did not work.

This does only work when I remove the content from the upper cell and set the background color to clear.
This means, the content in my upper cell covers my UIView, that's why I tried to call `bringSubViewToFront`, but this did also not work.

What am I doing wrong?

This is how I add the custom `UIView` to the cell's `contentView`:

```
CustomView *view=[[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [DeviceInformation getWidth], [self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath])];
[cell.contentView addSubview:view];
```

and in my `CustomView` I am adding another `UIView`, which should be then presented among multiple Cells.

Thanks!

Comment: What parent are you adding the Subview to?

Comment: I am adding the UIView in another UIView which is then added to the Cell

Comment: Cell Contains Multiple Subviews itself are you adding to contentview? Or to the Cell itself?

"If you want to go beyond the predefined styles, you can add subviews to the contentView property of the cell. When adding subviews, you are responsible for positioning those views and setting their content yourself."
-https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I am adding it to the cell itself: [cell addSubView: …]

Comment: Try adding it to the contentview see if that helps

Comment: hmmm…no it does not work.

as I wrote above, the UIView is visible in the upper cell, when I remove the content from this cell. So I think there's a problem with the order the views are added?

Comment: Could you post some code?

Comment: Why don't you redesign your UITableViewCell to avoid such problems. You can merge to cells into one view and display that in a single cell.

Comment: I agree I believe the cell are stacked so that the cells on towards the top of the list sit above the cells below the list. It makes more sense to go with @KunalBalan solution.

Comment: I agree with @KunalBalani's suggestion. However, if I don't deviate with your original issue...you know that every time a cell is re-queued in your table and is drawn (once they appear after scrolling), they are sort of *above* the other cells. One idea would be to call a `bringSubviewToFront` on your custom view **each** time a new cell is displayed (`willDisplayCell`). Here you can check if `visibleCells` contains your custom cell. If yes, call bring subview to front.